# Find the probability function of $N$ and $X_1$

Tags: probability

Scatter $3$ balls in $3$ cells, let $N$ be the number of taken cell, let $X_1$ be the number of balls in the first cell

> Find the probability function of $N$ and $X_1$

My start:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline &1&2&3\\\hline
  0 & &&0 \\\hline
  1 &  \\\hline
 2 & &&0 \\\hline
 3& &0&0 \\\hline
\end{array}

I'm stuck here

Comment: Can a cell hold one ball or multiple balls?

Comment: ..multiple balls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throwing the balls in the cells is the same as assigning a number to each ball. For the first ball you have $3$ choices, for the second ball $3$ and for the third $3$. Example (111) means all three balls go to cell 1 etc. So each outcome is equally likely and therefore, since there are $27$ outcomes, the probability of each is equal to $1/27$. Now,

\begin{align}P(X_1=0, N=1)&=P((222)\text{ or } (333))=\frac{2}{27}\\P(X_1=0, N=2)&=P((322),(232),(223) \text{ or } (332),(323),(233))=\frac{6}{27}\\P(X_1=1,N=1)&=0
\\P(X_1=1, N=2)&=P((122),(212),(221) \text{ or } (331),(313),(133))=\frac{6}{27}
\\P(X_1=1, N=3)&=P((123),(132),(213),(231),(312),(321))=\frac{6}{27}
\\P(X_1=2, N=1)&=0
\\P(X_1=2, N=2)&=P((112),(121),(211) \text{ or } (113),(131),(311))=\frac{6}{27}
\\P(X_1=3, N=1)&=P((111))=\frac1{27}
\end{align}

This is not the most efficient way, but is secure (you avoid binomials by treating (223) different as (232) but the cost is that you must count outcomes carefully).

---

Check that it is correct (not criminally wrong): All the probabilities add up to $1$.